# Does this specific build to use Booming Blade at a range of 20 feet work?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, attack, metamagic, reach

It has already been shown [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/114080) that the *booming blade* cantrip and the Spell Sniper feat do work together, and [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/112271) that the Sorcerer's Distant Spell Metamagic option and Spell Sniper also stack.

I am wondering if there is any reason the following build does not work:

Alice is a Bugbear multiclassed Sorcerer/Fighter (Battle Master) with the Spell Sniper feat, and she casts *booming blade*.

The range of *booming blade* is usually 5 feet. However, she has Spell Sniper which doubles the range to 10 feet, and she uses Distant Spell, which doubles the range again, to 20 feet.

She is holding a reach weapon, which has a reach of 10 feet. And she uses the Battle Master maneuver Lunging Attack, which increases the reach to 15. She then benefits from the Bugbear's Long-Limbed Feature, which increases the reach to 20.

Thus *booming blade* has a range of 20 feet and Alice has a reach of 20 feet, and so she can use *booming blade* from 20 feet away.

Is this correct? Have I correctly interpreted how these features work together to allow *booming blade* to work from 20 feet away?

Comment: Related: [Does the bugbear's long-limbed ability apply to melee spell attacks like shocking grasp?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/123914) and [What build maximizes reach?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/111256)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### As of November 10th 2020, this doesn’t work.

On November 10th, 2020, *booming blade* was changed to have a range of self, so is no longer eligible for spell sniper or distant spell metamagic.

Spell Sniper says:

> When you cast a spell that requires you to make an attack roll, the spell’s range is doubled.

Self cannot be doubled.

Distant Spell says:

> When you cast a spell that has a range of 5 feet or greater, you can spend 1 sorcery point to double the range of the spell.

Self is not 5 feet or greater.

Comment: Worth pointing out that the spell's range is Self (5-foot radius) which [is not the same thing as Self](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/177381/48793) and therefore it doesn't seem like we can treat it the same way as this answer suggests is the case.

Answer (score 8):

### Yes

Battlemaster's Lunging Strike requires a melee weapon attack:

> **When you make a melee weapon attack on your turn**, you can expend one superiority die to increase your reach for that attack by 5 feet.

Usually, a spell would involve a melee **spell** attack (things like Shocking Grasp or Vampiric Touch, for example). Booming Blade is an odd duck in that in that the spell results in a melee (non spell) attack:

> You brandish the weapon used in the spell’s casting and make a melee attack with it against one creature within 5 feet of you.

The spell has a range of "Self (5-foot radius)." This is kind of an odd phrasing because it's not quite just "self," which would have a range of 0 and therefore not benefit from Lunging Strike.

The 5 foot radius corresponds to the attack you make against a creature "within 5 feet of you" clause of the description. Because the 5-radius is explicitly mentioned within the range parameter of the spell, it means that you are permitted to use Lunging Strike, Spell Sniper, and/or Distant Spell Metamagic on Booming Blade.

Comment: On November 10th, 2020, booming blade was changed to have a range of self, so is no longer eligible for spell sniper or distant spell metamagic.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I think that comment would be worthy of its own answer.

Comment: @WakiNadiVellir Right, but Rykara is fairly active, and I’d prefer to give them a chance to edit.

Comment: @thom I've edited my answer but I don't believe the thesis changes as a result of the errata. It's clear that you think it is now incorrect, however, so I think it would be very beneficial to provide a contrary answer to more fully address the issue :-)