# Does the Spell Sniper feat double the range of booming blade when you are not wielding a reach weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, cantrips, reach

When using a weapon without reach, does the range of booming blade still double if you have spell sniper?

Comment: Related, non-dupe (it's specifically *with* a reach weapon): [Does Booming Blade and Spell Sniper Stack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/114080/52137)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### As of November 10th 2020, this doesn’t work.

On November 10th, 2020, *booming blade* was changed to have a range of self, so is no longer eligible for spell sniper. See [this errata document](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SCAG-Errata.pdf) for the *Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide*.

I will preserve the original answer for those who elect to ignore this errata.

---

#### The range of the spell doubles, but trivially so.

The first bullet of [Spell Sniper](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/spell-sniper) says:

> When you cast a spell that requires you to make an attack roll, the spell’s range is doubled.

This [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/114083/62294) goes into detail about the interaction between Spell Sniper and *booming blade*. The short verion is, as Rubiksmoose writes:

> Spell sniper will work because booming blade has an attack roll involved in it as long as you have a weapon capable of making a melee attack.

So it *technically* doubles the range of the spell, but this adjustment is entirely trivial without a reach weapon: with a reach of 5 feet, you can still only make an attack on a creature within 5 feet. *Booming blade* doesn’t extend the reach of your non-reach weapon, but the range of the spell is technically 10 feet with spell sniper, though it still fails if you do not make a melee attack against a creature (or cannot).

#### Unless you are a bugbear!

The [bugbear playable race](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/bugbear#BugbearTraits) has a feature called Long-Limbed:

> When you make a melee attack on your turn, your reach for it is 5 feet greater than normal.

So even with a non-reach weapon, Spell Sniper would enable the bugbear to use *booming blade* on targets 10 feet away. In this case, it's actually very important to understand that the range of the spell *is* actually doubled.

Comment: You can also use other features such as the Battle Master Fighter's Lunging Strike Maneuver, discussed [in my own question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/150444)

Comment: Would it also allow you to cast the spell when the desired target is 10 feet away, and move to within 5 feet to hit them? This might be relevant for avoiding a foe with the ability to attack if you cast a spell, and could be allowable since although the attack is part of the same action, you can move between Extra Attack attacks which are part of a single Attack action.

Comment: @GuybrushMcKenzie I don’t think that works, see here: [Can you move between the separate attacks of a spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/169144/can-you-move-between-the-separate-attacks-of-a-spell)

Comment: @ThomasMarkov good catch - thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## *Booming Blade* is limited by the weapon's reach

*Booming Blade* states:

> As part of the action used to cast this spell, you must make a melee attack with a weapon against one creature within the spell’s range, otherwise the spell fails.

The melee attack must target a creature within the range of the spell but that does not affect the reach of the melee weapon. If the target is outside of your reach then the spell fails.